# Scope of Functions as objects in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, scope

I am trying to understand how python stores and accesses its functions as objects .
For example take the following code-

```
def make_pretty(func):
    def inner():
        print("I got decorated")
        func()
        return func
    return inner

def ordinary():
    print("I am ordinary 2")

ordinary()
pretty=make_pretty(ordinary)

pretty()
```

When executed , pretty() returns

```
I got decorated
I am ordinary 2
<function __main__.ordinary()>
```

which seems to imply that the ordinary() function passed to make_pretty() is accessed as in the main scope, and as dir(pretty) doesn't show ordinary (Please correct me if i am wrong). 
Now if I run this code after this

```
def ordinary():
    print("I am ordinary 3")

pretty()
```

I still get the same output as before , even though I have the changed the global definition of ordinary , i.e. pretty still is considering the previous definition of ordinary even though I have redefined ordinary and the func in pretty is referring to global ordinary

Why is this so? I clearly am wrong somewhere but I don't understand where.
Some insight would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should read more about object references in python.

Comment: I read about object references from https://www.python-course.eu/passing_arguments.php , from what I understand in this case , ordinary is called by reference until it is changed , and when it is changed it becomes call by value . is this correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> even though I have the changed the global definition of ordinary ,
>   i.e. pretty still is considering the previous definition of ordinary
>   even though I have redefined ordinary and the func in pretty is
>   referring to global ordinary

You didn't change the function object that `pretty` refers to. You created a new function, and gave the name `ordinary` to it. The original function still exists, but can no longer be referred to by the name `ordinary`.

`pretty` doesn't know about all this. It refers to the original function all the time.

#### Before

Both the name "ordinary" and the function `pretty` refer to the same function:

```
<function 1>  <-- "ordinary"
              <-- pretty
```

#### After

The name "ordinary" refers to a new function, but `pretty` still refers to the original function:

```
<function 1>  <-- pretty

                "ordinary" -->  <function 2>
```

Comment: Yeah understood that after using id for the function , thanks anyway